# Module Artifacts and Dependencies Data from Artifactory Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I'm trying to replicate what the module and dependencies data as referenced [here](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration). Currently when we deploy an artifact to Artifactory from Jenkins none of the dependency and module information is supplied.

Our project has a defined pom.xml, but none of the information as demonstrated below is populating. How does Jenkins get this dependency information to send to Artifactory? We are using Artifactory Pro.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. 
Can you please elaborate? You want to understand what BuildInfo contains?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: How do you build? Build tool? Build server?

Comment: We use Jenkins, which is a build server.

Comment: Please refer to @drorb's answer, it's perfectly correct.

Comment: I have checked @drorb's answer. And while it is correct, it does no address the information I am trying to find. That is why I have edited my question in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: as @drorb mentioned, you need to either use one of Artifactory CI servers plugins (Jenkins, in your case) or one of the Artifactory build tools plugins (Maven in your case). Please refer to the documentation he mentions for the installation and configuration instructions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have this information inside Artifactory you should use the [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) (the question tags suggests you are using Jenkins) in order to deploy your build results into Artifactory.
The integration is available for Gradle, Maven, Ivy and freestyle build jobs.
When using the plugin to deploy your build results to Artifactory, the plugin will send a [BuildInfo](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info) data object to Artifactory (via REST) at the end of deployment. BuildInfo is a structured JSON object containing all the data about the build environment, artifacts and dependencies. This information is collected by the plugin during the build process and reflects what was actually used/done (this is not based on static analysis of your build). The information is collected using various types of build-info extractors (per build technology), for example, in the case of Maven jobs the information is collected from Maven by installing a Maven [execution listener](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/ExecutionListener.html).
For freestyle jobs there is support for [generic builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds). If your freestyle job is executing a Maven build, you can alternatively use the [Maven Artifactory Plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) in order to collect and deploy the build-info.

The JSON representation of the data looks something like this (but with much more info):

```
{
  "version" : "1.0.1",
  "name" : "build-name",
  "number" : "100",
  "type" : "MAVEN",
  "buildAgent" : {
    "name" : "Maven",
    "version" : "3.0.5"
  },
  "agent" : {
    "name" : "Jenkins",
    "version" : "1.534"
  },
  "modules" : [ {
    "id" : "org.foo:bar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
    "artifacts" : [ {
      "type" : "jar",
      "sha1" : "b790a0659bf001a64ee2ca88590e4bc6e0818f4b",
      "md5" : "0879ee3509f623c58a40a9db30df8090",
      "name" : "bar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    },],
    "dependencies" : [ {
      "type" : "jar",
      "sha1" : "686ef3410bcf4ab8ce7fd0b899e832aaba5facf7",
      "md5" : "b45be74134796c89db7126083129532f",
      "id" : "commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3",
      "scopes" : [ "provided" ]
    }]
  }
}
```

When using the OSS version of Artifactory, Build Integration includes the Generic BuildInfo View and the ability to traverse and view build information using Artifactory's [REST APIs](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BUILDS). Module Artifacts and Dependencies View, Repository View of Builds and the ability to export and manipulate build items require the Pro version.

To use the Jenkins Artifactory plugin, follow the instructions provided [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin).

Comment: Yes, but where does Jenkins get that information to send to Artifactory? Our project includes a pom.xml, but none of the dependency information is appearing. So where does Jenkins get the information to put in the BuildInfo to send to Artifactory?

Comment: Artifactory Jenkins plugin installs Maven Listener that monitors the build and collects the information.

Comment: So would the answer to my questions be that Jenkins retrieves build and dependency data from Maven? So does that mean in order for Jenkins to access this data I would need to configure the job as a Maven job? Is it not possible for Jenkins to get this data from it's listeners with a Freestyle job?

Comment: If you are executing Maven from a freestyle job you can use the [Maven Artifactory plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) to capture the build info

Comment: Ok, so the answer is that the buildInfo date is retrieved from build tool listeners. If I create a Maven job, then Jenkins will handle using the listeners to retrieve the data. If I've created a freestyle job, then I'll need to include the Maven Artifactory plugin to retrieve the data?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the additional information in the comments